# Is The Seiberg-Witten Map Unique?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, phase-space, poisson-brackets, non-commutative-theory

From my understanding the [Seiberg-Witten map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg-Witten_map) is a way to convert a non-commutative field theory into a commutative field theory. For example for the commutative relation between positions $[x, y]=i \theta$ the  common SW map I see in the literature for non commutative quantum mechanics is

$$x\rightarrow x_{c}-\frac{1}{2} \theta p_{y}$$

$$y\rightarrow y_{c}+\frac{1}{2} \theta p_{x}$$

Where $[x_{c},y_{c}]=0$ and $[x^{i}_{c},p_{j}]=i\delta^{i}_{j}$.

However the transformation

$$x\rightarrow x_{c}- \theta p_{y}$$

$y\rightarrow y_{c}$ Also satisfies  $[x, y]=i \theta$. Does this mean that $x\rightarrow x_{c}- \theta p_{y}$ $y\rightarrow y_{c}$ is also a valid Seiberg-Witten map? If it isn't, then what properties is this transformation missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Canonical transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) by definition preserve the canonical bracket. Therefore, you can always compose any SW map with a CT to yield another SW map. In this sense, the SW is very much non-unique. The advantage of the one written in the OP is that it is rather symmetrical with respect to $x,y$.

Comment: I do not think this answers the question in the spirit it was asked. Canonical transformation offers reparametrization of the *same theory*, so combining SWM with CT produces the same theory. You write: *In this sense, the SW is … non-unique*, but what about other senses? Is application of different versions of SW always equivalent to canonical/gauge etc. transformation?